# WSO2 Analytics 'certificate_unknown' error

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to use WSO2 Analytics on Windows 10.
My WSO2 Identity Server's version is 5.10.0 and Analytics' one is 5.8.0

To test WSO2 Analytics, I ran WSO2 Identity Server by executing 'wso2server.bat', and executed 'worker.bat' and 'dashboard.bat' sequentially to start Analytics.

Afterwards, once I enter 'https://localhost:9643/portal/', I faced an error below.

```
ERROR {org.wso2.transport.http.netty.contractimpl.listener.SslHandshakeCompletionHandlerForServer} - Error while SSL handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs, because identity server client trust-store does not contains analytic server's public certificate. To fix this

1. export analytics public certificate from keystore

   keytool -export -keystore /resource/security/wso2carbon.jks -alias  -file <wsoAs2carbon.cer>
2. Add the publc certificate to client-truststore.jks of identity server

   keytool -import -alias  -file <AScarbon.cer> -keystore /repository/resource/security/client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon

Ref https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/prerequisites-to-publish-statistics/#step-04-change-the-admin-password-and-add-key-store-certificates